# Dynamic delegate convert to dynamic function

Tags: c#, delegates, rhino-mocks

I'd like to copy an object into a mock of the same Interface. The goal is, to do it dynamic. But it seems, that there is no way to convert a dynamic delegate into a function.

```
public static T GetCopiedMock<T>(T toCopy, T mockObject) where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = GetPropertyInfos(toCopy, typeof(T));

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var result = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        var lamda = Expression.Lambda(result, parameter);
        var compilat = lamda.Compile();
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), property.PropertyType);

        //Here is my problem
        mockObject.Expect(new Func<T, property.PropertyType>(compilat));
    }

    return mockObject;
}
```

I know its not possible directly since propertytype is at runtime but is there is any workaround?

By the way, this is my first post. So if you see something terrible which i have to do better, tell me!

Comment: your `funcType` variable isn't being used.  Is there a specific thing you wanted to do with it?

Comment: Also, I can't find the `Expect` method that you are using?  Is that part of a framework?  Since `T` is a class, it will only have the `System.Object` methods associated with it by default.

Comment: No `funcType` right now not. I thought it helps maybe

Comment: `Expect` is an extension of Rhino Mock. This method needs an argument like this `Func<T,R>`